# How to automatically press the cancel button with console chrome when pop-up box appears?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I am preventing chrome from reloading with:

```
javascript:window.onbeforeunload = function() { return false }
```

in the console.

But it returns a pop-up with a cancel option when triggered and I manually need to press cancel.

What would it look like to press cancel when the pop-up is triggered so I can go about my business using javascript in the console?

Comment: window.onbeforeunload = function() { return; }

Comment: @Yogi does nothing